# Adding item in redux store array seems to just update it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux

I am trying to create a cash register system. Now I want to create an order list, which contains products and how many of each I sold. I am using redux store here.

My problem is when I use the ADDORDERITEM case, it receives an action.order like {id: 1, name:"halve zolen", categoryId:1, price: 1.0} for example. In the case statement, the numberOfOrderItems gets set to what number is at that moment in the state.numberOfOrderItems.
This works for one item, but if I add the same item with a different amount, I end up with an array with 2 objects with the amount that was last entered, while this should be 2 different amounts here. If I check action.order after I set the numberOfOrderItems it is a correct order, so what is going wrong here? My guess it has something to do with me using state.numberOfOrderItems here which make a subscription to that, and updates it whenever this variable is used somewhere. Is there some way to just take a snapshot of it and never update it again?

My code:
Store.js:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';

const kassaReducer = (state = {orders: [], numberOfOrderItems: ""}, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case "ADDORDERITEM":            
            let newOrder = action.order;          
            newOrder.numberOfOrderItems = state.numberOfOrderItems;
            return {orders: [...state.orders, newOrder], numberOfOrderItems: ""};
        case "REMOVEORDERITEM":
            return {orders : state.orders.remove(state.orders.indexOf(action.order)), numberOfOrderItems: state.numberOfOrderItems};
        case "SETITEMNUMBER":
            return {orders : state.orders, numberOfOrderItems: state.numberOfOrderItems === "" ? action.numberOfOrderItems : (state.numberOfOrderItems + action.numberOfOrderItems)};
    }
    return state;
}

const store = createStore(kassaReducer);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
Ok I read your post one more time

This still is invalid and is causing problems:

```
action.order.numberOfOrderItems = state.numberOfOrderItems;
```

but it should be:

```
case "ADDORDERITEM":
  return {orders: [...state.orders, action.order], numberOfOrderItems: state.numberOfOrderItems + action.numberOfOrderItems };
```

Comment: No the state.numberOfOrderItems should not be updated, this is a value that arrives here correctly already, its the action.order.numberOfOrderItems that needs updating

Comment: It goes wrong when I try to add this action.order to my existing array of orders in the state, when the same order is in it with a different numberOfOrderItems, it changes the first object too, while it should just add my second object without changing anything

Comment: `acion` should never be updated

Comment: okay, if I do it like this: let newOrder = action.order;          
            newOrder.numberOfOrderItems = state.numberOfOrderItems; problem stays the same though

Comment: You are still updating action instead of updating the state

Comment: yeah state doesn't need to be updated here

Comment: I updated the answer. But I don't know what `numberOfOrderItems` should do really. But still, updating the action causes the error

Comment: well i'm using buttons (with numbers as value) to tell how many I'm going to sell of a product, before using the button to add that product to my orders list. the amount is going to be kept in that state.numberOfOrderItems, because it registered in a totally different component than the one I use to dipslay the order list.. That's why it has a correct value when I enter that specific case, and I just want to add that amount to the object that contains the order that I'm going to add to my list..

Comment: Try the current version

Comment: solved it by creating a whole new object, so you were indeed right about changing the action was causing the error, thanks! let newOrder = {name: action.order.name, price: action.order.price, amount: state.numberOfOrderItems};

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, it looks like you're using some legacy-style patterns for Redux+React-Redux. "Modern Redux" with Redux Toolkit and the React-Redux hooks API should help simplify your code and be easier to work with.  In particular, RTK's `createSlice` API uses Immer inside to let you write "mutating" syntax in reducers, which then get handled as correct immutable updates.

See our Redux docs tutorials for details:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index